# normxcorr2 vs. normxcorr2_general in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

There is a file called normxcorr2_general on MathWorks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29005-generalized-normalized-cross-correlation) that the author claims always gives correct answers while Matlab's built-in normxcorr2 gives incorrect answers when the two input matrices are close in size. After doing some testing, it is clear that the two functions do give significantly different outputs when the inputs are the same size.

Is normxcorr2_general actually more accurate? I don't have much experience in Matlab and I'm having trouble figuring that out from reading through the function script.

Edit: To clarify, if I understand it correctly then these functions are both implementing equation number (2) in [this](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.pdf) paper about computing normalized cross-correlations.

Comment: Is it possible to check the answers and see for yourself?  What does it give answers to? i.e. What operation does it perform on matrices?

Comment: It's implementing equation (2) from [this](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.pdf) paper. I would check the answers with that, but the equation is fairly complicated and I would like to know whether the function is still accurate with larger input matrices (which I think are too big to reasonably check by hand).